# Error: "The system network services are not compatible with this version."

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, indicator

I've been using Ubuntu 14.04 since 3-4 weeks now, and I suddenly encountered this error upon starting my computer today.

It should be noted that **the internet works**, but I am unable to see the Wifi indicator. The network settings take a while to load, and this is what I see once it loads: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XRBt.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.